# How can I insert a script in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, adsense

I want to add this into innerHTML in javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.defineSlot('xxxxxxxxxxxx', [160, 600], 'div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxx').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
googletag.enableServices();
</script>
<div id='div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxx' style='width:160px; height:600px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxx');
</script>
</div>
```

It always breaks my code no matter what I do.

Do you have an idea of what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: show us the part where you do `no matter what I do`

Comment: ... and any error messages you get.

Comment: Why do you want to insert that with innerHTML? Just add the div and then call the functions. Generating a new script element seems unnecessarily twiddly.

Comment: Can you just show me how you would do it. Just write please an innerHTML with this tag so I can understand what is wrong. @Thilo

Comment: The error is that it's not coming up good like text does.. it's the rest of the code like it was part of this text and not code. @SiGanteng